# What's wrong with this case SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, case, mysql-error-1064

maybe you can help, I'm using this case query, and I'm trying to do mysql weighting with it. What's wrong with it?

```
  SELECT *
    FROM cronjob_reloaded
   WHERE site IN ('site1.com', 'site2.com')
ORDER BY (CASE site
            WHEN 'site1.com' THEN 0.2
            WHEN 'site2.com' THEN 0.8    ) * RAND( ) DESC
   LIMIT 0 , 30
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') * RAND() DESC
>       LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the right syntax of CASE

```
SELECT *
FROM cronjob_reloaded
WHERE site IN ('site1.com', 'site2.com' )
ORDER BY (
  CASE 
    WHEN site = 'site1.com' THEN 0.2
    WHEN site = 'site2.com' THEN 0.8 
  END
) * RAND( ) DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: ty very much, it works. Becouse i have way many entries from site1 in my database I'm trying to create an sql wich gets only 20% from site 1 and the rest from site2

Answer (score 3):

CASE must be closed with END:

```
CASE site
WHEN 'site1.com'
THEN 0.2
WHEN 'site2.com'
THEN 0.8
END -- Added this END to your query's CASE
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is that you have not used END CASE.

Change:

```
CASE site
WHEN 'site1.com'
THEN 0.2
WHEN 'site2.com'
THEN 0.8
)
```

To:

```
CASE site
WHEN 'site1.com'
THEN 0.2
WHEN 'site2.com'
THEN 0.8
END CASE
```

Refer to: [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)